# Vue: Displaying nested data in a table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, handlebars.js

I'm in the process of rewriting some older code, and using Vue as the replacement. It's all going great apart from changing one table that is templated using handlebars.

Using handlebars nested `{{each}}` I can work down through the nested data structure while displaying the relevant data in table rows: e.g. using handlebars: https://jsfiddle.net/6dsruo40/1/

I cant figure out how to do the same using Vue with `v-for` etc.

Fiddle with as mush as I have: https://jsfiddle.net/cj7go6bv/

I don't know how to work through the data structure while maintaining the `<tr>`s like in handlebars

This is the data structure I'm using, but it is flexible:

```
var data = [
  {
key: "Region 1",
values: [
  {
    key: "Sub region 1",
    values: [
      {
        site: "Site A",
        timestamp: 1507246300935,
        total: 3,
      },
      {
        site: "Site B",
        timestamp: 1507246300818,
        total: 0,
      },
      {
        site: "Site C",
        timestamp: 1507246300936,
        total: 0,
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    key: "Sub region 2",
    values: [
      {
        site: "Site A",
        timestamp: 1507246301442,
        total: 20,
      },
      {
        site: "Site B",
        timestamp: 1507246301788,
        total: 5,
      }
    ]
   },
  {
    key: "Sub region 3",
    values: [
      {
        site: "Site A",
        timestamp: 1507246302503,
        total: 66,
      },
      {
        site: "Site B",
        timestamp: 1507246302783,
        total: 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
   },
   {
key: "Region 2",
values: [
  {
    key: "Sub region 1",
    values: [
      {
        site: "Site A",
        timestamp: 1507246306789,
        total: 0,
      },
      {
        site: "Site B",
        timestamp: 1507246307439,
        total: 6,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key: "Sub region 2",
    values: [
      {
        site: "Site A",
        timestamp: 1507246308269,
        total: 10,
      },
      {
        site: "Site B",
        timestamp: 1507246308683,
        total: 30,
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
];
```

The Vue code I have is very modest so far:

```
Vue.component('project-table', {
  template: '#table-template',
  props: {
    data: Array
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#table-container',
    data: {data: sites},
    });
```

And the template:

```
<div id="table-container">
  <project-table :data="data"></project-table>
</div>
    <script id="table-template" type="text/x-template">
        <table class="u-full-width">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Project location</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>Timestamp</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="name-row" v-for="item in data">
            <th class="name" colspan="3">{{item.key}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
    </table>
</script>
```

What is the mechanism in Vue for displaying a table like is done in Handlebars? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the relevant part of the template updated.

```
<tbody>
  <template v-for="item in data">
    <tr class="name-row" >
      <th class="name" colspan="3">{{item.key}}</th>
    </tr>
    <template v-for="subregion in item.values">
      <tr>
        <th class="group-name" colspan="4">{{subregion.key}}</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="site in subregion.values">
        <td>{{site.site}}</td>
        <td>{{site.total}}</td>
        <td>
          <span>{{site.timestamp}}</span>
        </td>  
      </tr>
    </template>
  </template>
<tbody>
```

And the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cj7go6bv/1/).

The main point is taking advantage of the `template` element to render more than one `tr` per iteration.

Comment: That is fantastic @bert! So simple. `<template>` is like a transparent wrapper of sorts is it? I really struggled to find relevant info on google or SO. Thanks!

Comment: Is using template inside a template allowed?

Comment: @AlexanderKim Yep.

Comment: Not the clean way. Prettier will throw exceptions: ```Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives```, ```'<template>' cannot be keyed. Place the key on real elements instead ```

Comment: it's easy to implement